# send data object from xml to viewmodel

Tags: java, android, xml, mvvm

how can i send data object it self to view model ? when i'm trying to do that i found null object !

XML :

```
  <variable
        name="signUpObject"
        type="com.rabe7.community.model.request.register.RegisterRequest" />


    <variable
        name="signUpClickListener"
        type="com.rabe7.community.view_model.user_management.RegisterViewModel" />


      <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_sign_up_submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp8w"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> signUpClickListener.onRegisterSubmitClicked(signUpObject)}"
                    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/dp8w">
```

RegisterViewModel:

```
   public void onRegisterSubmitClicked(RegisterRequest registerRequest){

}
```

why this object null ? 
i want to bind all data on xml and send the full data object to viewmodel to use it

XML :

```
         <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_sign_up_email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/label_email"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@={signUpObject.userEmail}" />

   <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_sign_up_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:hint="@string/label_sign_up_password"
                        android:imeActionLabel="SignIn"
                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="@={signUpObject.userPassword}" />
```

so user enter his email and phone and then click submit .. and the object that hold email and phone delivered to viewmdol

and this is the data class

```
public class RegisterRequest extends BaseObservable {


@SerializedName("Email")
private String userEmail;
@SerializedName("Password")
private String userPassword;
@Expose
private String userConfirmPassword;
@SerializedName("Phone")
private String userPhone;
@SerializedName("ImagePath")
private String imagePath;
@SerializedName("Name")
private String userName;

//getters

@Bindable
public String getUserEmail() { return userEmail; }
@Bindable
public String getUserPassword() { return userPassword; }
@Bindable
public String getUserConfirmPassword(){return userConfirmPassword;}
@Bindable
public String getUserPhone() { return userPhone; }
@Bindable
public String getImagePath() { return imagePath; }
@Bindable
public String getUserName() { return userName; }

//setters

public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
    this.userEmail = userEmail;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userEmail);
}
public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
    this.userPassword = userPassword;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userPassword);
}
public void setUserConfirmPassword(String userConfirmPassword) {
    this.userConfirmPassword = userConfirmPassword;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userConfirmPassword);
}
public void setUserPhone(String userPhone) {
    this.userPhone = userPhone;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userPhone);
}
public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.imagePath);
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.userName);
}
```

}

forgive me for my bad English

Comment: Add your viewModel implementation and where you are using DataBinding, so either Fragment or Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set these variables in your activity/fragment? I would like to point out these objects act like variables and don't have a value by default. First, we initialise the data-binding object in our activity/fragment then we call binding.setSignUpObject() and binding.setSignUpClickListener() to set these.

If your have already called these function in activity, please add relevant code where you initialised these.